# What would happen to a Sith/Dark Jedi seeking redemption?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, sith

Perhaps spoiler alert even 14 years after release : the *Star Wars Jedi Knight: Jedi Academy* 2003 video game.

---

I finished the game *Jedi Academy* once more yesterday, opting for the Dark Side when required to choose, and from then until the end, Kyle Katarn kept telling Jaden Korr (the playable character) that it was not too late and he/she could come back to the Light Side, even though he/she killed about 25 Jedi apprentices in the last level.

So my question is : what would happen to a Sith/Dark Jedi if he decided to come back to the Light Side after having done such horrible acts ?

I assume it wouldn't be as easy as "It's ok now, let's forget about it." and that he'd somehow have to pay for what he did, but is it known what would happen ? (a trial, a pilgrimage, exile, etc.)

As English is not my native language, I might be hard to understand, so feel free to ask more explanations !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best reference from the new canon would probably be the novel "Dark Disciple". This post will contain spoilers for that book, obviously - I'll keep them vague until explicitly stated, otherwise.

It illustrates how the Jedi Council is willing to reinstate fallen Jedi after a hearing, but might put candidates under surveillance until it is considered proven that they indeed are back in the Light. This fits well with Jedi philosophy, because considering someone lost forever would be an extreme more befitting the Sith way.

Furthermore, it shows the spiritual journey of a Jedi's fall and way back, as well as the redemption of a long time servant of the dark side. So, both are possible: the process of returning from the Dark Side and the formal redemption before the Jedi Council.

*[Warning: More detailed spoilers ahead!]*

In "Dark Disciple" the reader witnesses Quinlan Vos' fall to the Dark Side, as well as his being forgiven and welcomed back, prematurely, and, ultimately his redemption.

After having fallen, Vos is captured and deceives the Jedi into believing he's come back to the Light. He is welcomed back and promptly betrays the Jedi. Later on, after his alignment shifts again, he gives himself up to Jedi custody, once more. In a hearing, the Council decides to reinstate Vos, although under surveillance until he's conclusively proven redeemed, because he has shown mercy to an enemy he had the chance to kill and because the Council feels they were partially responsible for his fall in the first place, by sanctioning the assassination of Dooku and assigning Vos to the task.

Meanwhile, Asajj Ventress abandons the Dark Side through learning about Vos and experiencing some of the Jedi way first-hand, leading her to the ultimate act of selflessness.